# ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'nonPdr'

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, image-processing, keras

I'm facing this error: ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'nonPdr', when I run this code:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(input_shape=(605,700,3), filters=64, kernel_size=(3,3), padding="valid",activation="tanh"))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(32, activation='tanh', input_dim=100))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

data, labels = ReadImages(TRAIN_DIR)

# Train the model, iterating on the data in batches of 32 samples
model.fit(np.array(data), np.array(labels), epochs=10, batch_size=32)
```

Detail: 'nonPdr' is one of my 2 img classes

**UPDATE** My readImg method

```py
def ReadImages(Path):
    ImageList = list()
    LabelList = list()
    ImageCV = list()

    # Get all subdirectories
    FolderList = os.listdir(Path)

    # Loop over each directory
    for File in FolderList:
        if(os.path.isdir(os.path.join(Path, File))):
            for Image in os.listdir(os.path.join(Path, File)):
                # Add the image path to the list
                ImageList.append(os.path.join(Path, File) + os.path.sep + Image)
                # Convert the path into a file
                ImageCV.append(cv2.imread(os.path.join(Path, File) + os.path.sep + Image))    
                # Add a label for each image and remove the file extension
                LabelList.append(os.path.splitext(File)[0])
        else:
            ImageList.append(os.path.join(Path, File))

            ImageCV.append(cv2.imread(os.path.join(Path, File) + os.path.sep + Image))    
            # Add a label for each image and remove the file extension
            LabelList.append(os.path.splitext(File)[0])

    return ImageCV, LabelList
```

Comment: You are not providing enough detailes to help you. From your code, something must be wrong in ReadImages function. Everything else seems right

Comment: may be one hot encoding ur labelwill help : https://machinelearningmastery.com/why-one-hot-encode-data-in-machine-learning/

Comment: @Sherzod I update the post with the ReadImages method

Comment: I posted answer for your question :). By the way, why do you need ImageList variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your ReadImages function, you are making list of strings:

```
LabelList.append(os.path.splitext(File)[0])
```

And later when you use ReadImages function, you are trying to convert this list of strings into numpy array. Here:

```
data, labels = ReadImages(TRAIN_DIR)
model.fit(np.array(data), np.array(labels), epochs=10, batch_size=32)
```

Possible solution might be assigning your class names to numbers:

```
classes = ["nonPdr", "another_class"]
LabelList.append(classes.index[os.path.splitext(File)[0]])
```

0 will be appended to LabelList when your class is "nonPdr", and 1 will be append if your class is "other_class".

Comment: The app runned very slow, consuming a lot of memory and shows this error:

Comment: run_metadata_ptr)

ResourceExhaustedError: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[32,605,700,64] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 by allocator cpu
  [[{{node training/RMSprop/gradients/max_pooling2d_5/MaxPool_grad/MaxPoolGrad}}]]
Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens, add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current allocation info.

Comment: Can you help me?