# How to shape images for labels

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, keras-layer

I am trying to train satellite images. My training set has 2 folders of input (samples) and ground truth (labels).

Total images are: `496`
My X_train shape is: `(496,3,256,256)`
and y_train shape is: `(496,256,256)`

For every model, I use I get an error regarding the dense layer.

```
ValueError: Expected dense to have 2 dimensions, but got an array with shape (496,256,256)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are feeding images to the Dense Layer. Either flatten the images using .flatten() or use a model with CNN Layers. The shape (496,3,256,256) means you have 496 images of size 256x256 having 3 dimensions(rgb).

Look up on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57574251/9025861) for CNN model.

[CNN: Error when checking input: expected dense to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (391, 605, 700, 3)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57573624/9025861)